# Average result of multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is a question for all the array specialists out there. I have an multi dimension array with a result as number (can be 0,1 or 2) and need the average for each grouped by parent.

In the example below the calculation would be:

subentry1_sub1 = 2 + 2 = 4 (4/2=**2**)

subentry1_sub2 = 1 + 1 = 2 (2/2=**1**)

So what I try to archive in PHP is the following result:

**subentry1_sub1 average = 2**

**subentry1_sub2 average = 1**

...

I already tried some solutions from similar questions. But with all the recursive functions I didn't managed to get it aggregated by the last child name (e.g. subentry1_sub1).

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

subentry1_sub1 is 2 + 2 because its two times in the array

[entry1] => [subentry1] => [subentry1_sub1] => result

[entry2] => [subentry1] => [subentry1_sub1] => result

```
Array
(
    [entry1] => Array
        (
            [subentry1] => Array
                (
                    [subentry1_sub1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => abc
                            [result] => 2
                        )

                    [subentry1_sub2] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => abc
                            [result] => 1
                        )

                )

            [subentry2] => Array
                (
                    [subentry2_sub1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => abc
                            [result] => 1
                        )

                    [subentry2_sub2] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => abc
                            [result] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [entry2] => Array
        (
            [subentry1] => Array
                (
                    [subentry1_sub1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => abc
                            [result] => 2
                        )

                    [subentry1_sub2] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => abc
                            [result] => 1
                        )

                )

            [subentry2] => Array
                (
                    [subentry2_sub1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => abc
                            [result] => 1
                        )

                    [subentry2_sub2] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => abc
                            [result] => 1
                        )

                )

        )        
)
```

Comment: why is `subentry1_sub1 = 2 + 2`?

Comment: Because it's two times in the array:
[entry1] => [subentry1] => [subentry1_sub1] => result
[entry2] => [subentry1] => [subentry1_sub1] => result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. In this i have created a new `array` `$sum` which will add result value of same subentry childs with same key and another array `$count` which will count the number of times each key repeats

```
<?php   
    $data = array('entry1'=>array(
         'subentry1'=>
             array(
               'subentry1_sub1'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>2),
               'subentry1_sub2'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>1)
             ),
         'subentry2'=>
             array(
               'subentry2_sub1'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>1),
               'subentry2_sub2'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>1)
             )

          ),
     'entry2'=>array(
         'subentry1'=>
             array(
               'subentry1_sub1'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>2),
               'subentry1_sub2'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>1)
             ),
         'subentry2'=>
             array(
               'subentry2_sub1'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>1),
               'subentry2_sub2'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>1)
             )
          )
    );

$sum = array();
$repeat = array();

    foreach($data as $input){
        foreach($input as $array){
                foreach($array as $key=>$value){
                        if(array_key_exists($key,$sum)){
                        $repeat[$key] = $repeat[$key]+1;
                        $sum[$key] = $sum[$key] + $value['result'];
                        }else{
                        $repeat[$key] = 1;
                        $sum[$key] = $value['result'];                              
                }}}}                    
echo "<pre>";
print_r($sum);
print_r($repeat);  
foreach($sum as $key=>$value){
   echo $key. ' Average = '. $value/$repeat[$key]."</br>";  
    }
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [subentry1_sub1] => 4
    [subentry1_sub2] => 2
    [subentry2_sub1] => 2
    [subentry2_sub2] => 2
)
Array
(
    [subentry1_sub1] => 2
    [subentry1_sub2] => 2
    [subentry2_sub1] => 2
    [subentry2_sub2] => 2
)


subentry1_sub1 Average = 2
subentry1_sub2 Average = 1
subentry2_sub1 Average = 1
subentry2_sub2 Average = 1
```

You can easily calculate avg now

**Note** : As you mentioned you are counting occurence of `subentry1_sub1`  etc so i did the same so  it will also `count` whether key `result` exists or not

Comment: Thanks man! This is exactly what I searched for! It's working great.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but im pretty sure there is a much easier way of doing this for anyone who is interested:

If you know the result will always be a number:

```
foreach($my_array as $entry_name => $entry_data)
{
   foreach($entry_data as $sub_name => $sub_data) 
   {
      $sub_results = array_column($sub_data, 'result');
      $averages[$entry_name][$sub_name] = array_sum($sub_results)/count($sub_results);
   }
}
```

If its possible the result could be NULL or empty, this will check it and return 'N/A' if there is no valid data to calculate an average from:

```
foreach($my_array as $entry_name => $entry_data)
{
   foreach($entry_data as $sub_name => $sub_data) 
   {
      $sub_results = array_filter(array_column($sub_data, 'result'));
      $averages[$entry_name][$sub_name] = (count($sub_results) > 0 ? array_sum($sub_results)/count($sub_results) : 'N/A');
   }
}
```

both of these solutions will give you an averages array that will output the average per subentry per entry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this like,

```
<?php
    $data=array('entry1'=>array(
         'subentry1'=>
             array(
               'subentry1_sub1'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>3),
               'subentry1_sub2'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>3)
             ),
         'subentry2'=>
             array(
               'subentry2_sub1'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>2),
               'subentry2_sub2'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>8)
             )

          ),
     'entry2'=>array(
         'subentry1'=>
             array(
               'subentry1_sub1'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>6),
               'subentry1_sub2'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>6)
             ),
         'subentry2'=>
             array(
               'subentry2_sub1'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>10),
               'subentry2_sub2'=>array('value'=>'abc','result'=>12)
             )
          )
    );

    foreach($data as $k=>$v){
        echo "----------------$k---------------------\n";
        if(is_array($v)){
            foreach($v as $a=>$b){
                if(is_array($b)){
                    echo $a.' average = ';
                    $c=array_keys($b);// now get *_sub*
                    $v1=isset($b[$c[0]]['result']) ? $b[$c[0]]['result'] : '';
                    $v2=isset($b[$c[1]]['result']) ? $b[$c[1]]['result'] : '';
                    echo ($v1+$v2)/2;
                    echo "\n";
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
```

**[Online Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5953172ee2bcaaeae9ae5495ac1be7bce4b79b3)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The example above is just an excerpt. The real data are much much bigger. So hardcoding the keys won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found a simple working solution myself:

```
foreach ($data as $level2) {
    foreach ($level2 as $level3) {
        foreach ($level3 as $keyp => $level4) {
            foreach ($level4 as $key => $value) {
                if($key == 'result') $stats[$keyp] += $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With that you get the total for every key in an new array `$stats`.

But be sure to checkout the solution from `user1234`, too. It's working great and already includes the calculation of the average.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39292593/2466703