# Write string data to an array

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

I get temperature readings in the last hour. The data comes in the form of a line where data is displayed for every 10 minutes.

```
200504, 0530, 0, 262.3, 1.399, 6.097, 2.15, 
200504, 0540, 0, 251.2, 1.29, 6.08, 2.09,
200504, 0550, 0, 249.4, 1.685, 5.921, 2.44,
200504, 0600, 0, 249.5, 1.465, 5.904, 2.27,
200504, 0610, 0, 247.7, 1.801, 6.214, 2.61,
200504, 0620, 0, 246.9, 1.908, 6.532, 3.04,
```

It is necessary to calculate the average value of the last element of the row

```
$str = '190227, 2020, 9, 245.8, 2.886, 5.753, 0';

$pattern = '/([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*)/m';

preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);

$result =  [
    "Date" =>  intval($matches[1]),
    "Time" =>  intval($matches[2]),
    "h" => intval($matches[3]),
    "Deg.M" => floatval($matches[4]),
    "m/s" => floatval($matches[5]),
    "deg.C" => floatval($matches[6]),
    "mm/h" => floatval($matches[7])
];
```

With this solution, I get data for one time interval, but how can I write all this data into one array and calculate the average value?

Comment: Use explode instead? Way more easy to do what you want.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Split on `,\s+`. Done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Average result of multidimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291273/average-result-of-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: `200504, 0530, 0, 262.3, 1.399, 6.097, 2.15, ` is one line? or all your numbers in one line? ... from where you take the data? from a file .. or how they come.. 
you give to less explanations for your question.. and your example show just one line..

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, an example for one line. Before that, I needed to process only one line. And now there are several at a time, and for this they need to be written into an array.The data comes as indicated in the example as a string.

Comment: The number one rule in programming is Break The Problem Down. Your first task is to parse a file of comma-separated lines (commonly known as "CSV") into a multi-dimensional array; this is an extremely common task, and you should be able to find plenty of examples online. Your second task is to find an average from a list of numbers; then extend this to work with a multi-dimensional array. These two tasks don't depend on each other at all, but once you have both completed, putting them together will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could treat it like a CSV (Comma Seperated File), which it actially is:

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
$array = array_map('str_getcsv', $lines); 
print_r($array);
```

You might want to fancy it up a bit with a trim and some named keys, but this gets the bulk of the job done :)

Then, if you want all last values and sum/avg them:

```
$values = array_column($array, 6);
$avg = array_sum($values)/count($values);
```